# Count consecutive numbers from a column of a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has segments of consecutive values appearing in column `a` (the value in column `b` does not matter):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(150)
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a':[1,2,3,4,5,15,16,17,18,203,204,205],'b':np.random.randint(50000,size=(12))})
>>> df
      a      b
0     1  27066
1     2  28155
2     3  49177
3     4    496
4     5   2354
5    15  23292
6    16   9358
7    17  19036
8    18  29946
9   203  39785
10  204  15843
11  205  21917
```

I would like to add a column `c` whose values are sequential counts according to presenting consecutive values in column `a`, as shown below:

```
a   b       c
1   27066   1
2   28155   2
3   49177   3
4   496     4
5   2354    5
15  23292   1
16  9358    2
17  19036   3
18  29946   4
203 39785   1
204 15843   2
205 21917   3
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution:

```
df["c"] = (s := df["a"] - np.arange(len(df))).groupby(s).cumcount() + 1
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
      a      b  c
0     1  27066  1
1     2  28155  2
2     3  49177  3
3     4    496  4
4     5   2354  5
5    15  23292  1
6    16   9358  2
7    17  19036  3
8    18  29946  4
9   203  39785  1
10  204  15843  2
11  205  21917  3
```

The original idea comes from ancient Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/itertools.html#examples).

In order to use the walrus operator (`(:=)` or [assignment expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions)) you need Python 3.8+, instead you can do:

```
s = df["a"] - np.arange(len(df))
df["c"] = s.groupby(s).cumcount() + 1
print(df)
```

Comment: what does '(s := df["a"]' mean? I got error message on my python 3.7.9 "SyntaxError: invalid syntax". Is it a new function of new verion python?

Comment: Is the walrus operator, you need Python 3.8. Let me update the answer

Comment: OK, I modify it to : df['c'] = (df.assign(s=df["a"] - np.arange(len(df)))).groupby('s').cumcount()+1, it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to find consecutive groups, use [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) to get the number sequence and then remove any extra in later groups.

```py
a = df['a'].add(1).shift(1).eq(df['a'])
df['c'] = a.cumsum() - a.cumsum().where(~a).ffill().fillna(0).astype(int) + 1
df
```

Result:

```
      a      b  c
0     1  27066  1
1     2  28155  2
2     3  49177  3
3     4    496  4
4     5   2354  5
5    15  23292  1
6    16   9358  2
7    17  19036  3
8    18  29946  4
9   203  39785  1
10  204  15843  2
11  205  21917  3
```